# How to reference element controlled by *ngIf directive without template reference in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I want to obtain a reference to the element controlled by the `*ngIf` directive without using a template reference in Angular 6.

For example, I have:

```
<a *ngIf="allowAccessTo()" [routerLink]="['/home']" class="nav-item nav-link">Home</a>
```

I would like to have a reference to that  element, and specifically the href/pathname from the `[routerLink]`, inside my `allowAccessTo()` method but without having to add a template reference to the element.

Is there a way to do this?

I plan to use the href/pathname from the element to call into my role guard service.

I have it working if I pass the route into the `allowAccessTo()` method (`allowAccessTo('home')`) but would prefer to not have to do that.

This is my primary app navigation so there will be many links like this and even if I added a template reference, I wouldn't know which one to look at inside `allowAccessTo()` without being able to tell which element caused the `allowAccessTo()` method to be invoked.

Comment: I think you may want to consider checking which routes should display prior to rendering them in the template. Such as creating an array/map of routes that actually need to display (calling allowAccessTo()) in ngOnit calling or similar instead of attempting to us *ngIf for this specific use case. The route guards such as CanActivate, you can access the attempted path/url to do any additional validation as necessary.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I already tried an approach like that.  Yes, in ngOnInit(), I can access my canActivate() method and build a map of booleans that indicate if a route is allowed.  But then I still have to hardcode each link's route/boolean index into the link's ngIf expression to map it to the correct route which is effectively what I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding. If you can determine completely inside of `ngOnInit` whether a link should show or not via looping through some array of paths and calling allowAccessTo(currentPathOfIteration), why would need to render it at all? If a an array of routes to show is built in `ngOnInit()`, this avoid the need for `*ngIf` entirely as you could just render the ones with `show: true` or whatever. You may need to share your route guard as well as `allowAccessTo()` to help clarify what the issue entirely is.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselskySorry, I accidentally hit the enter key and saved my comment above prematurely and it won't let me save the completed response yet..

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I tried an approach like that.  But then I still have to hardcode each link's route index into the map in the link's ngIf expression to map it to the correct route which is effectively what I'm trying to prevent.

<a *ngIf="allowAccessTo['info']" [routerLink]="['/info']" class="nav-item nav-link">Info</a>

That's not much different.  I'm trying to prevent having to specify the route to check since it's already specified in the [routerLink] to prevent errors.  The route is provided in the [routerLink] so I'd like to be able to use that.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Also, I still want the links in the template because I want to control where in the menu structure each link is...to control the UI.  But I only want them to appear if the route is allowed.  As I mentioned, I have that working.  What I can't seem to do is obtain each link's route inside my ngIf expression's method that is called without hardcoding it in the expression.  Since [routerLink] has it, I would like to use it.  Something like,

<a *ngIf="allowAccessTo([routerLink])" [routerLink]="['/home']" class="nav-item nav-link">Home</a> 

but that doesn't work.

Comment: I think you may be understanding how route guards should be called/utilized. The route guard isn't something you call explicitly from a component. It's called internally by angular for any routes that have the respective guard listed in the routing configuration. If your goal is to not display certain links based on the value `allowAccessTo()`, then I believe that just making the [array of visible links](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwestw) in `ngOnInit()` would work. Then the displayed links, as the user clicks them, your additional logic in the actual route guard is called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183575/discussion-between-joe-rattz-and-alexander-staroselsky).

Answer (score 0):

Could you not create a variable in typescript file like: `currentRoute` and set this variable whenever you need to route? Then, this variable can be accessed in the function `allowAccessTo()` directly.

Comment: I'm not trying to control the routing here.  The router and my role guard service is doing that.  I'm trying to control which links are displayed to the user (so that links to disallowed routes are not displayed).